# Export single tenant app to multitenant with spring-boot

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

We have developed single tenant app and now we need to aggregate all apps and databases to one, to make multi tenant app. We are using Spring-Boot and Hibernate. Is there any tools for this job ? If somebody had a similar problem please share your experience.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this problem. I made sql stored procedure. First of all i make a tree of foreign key refs. After that I updated all ID's and merge old and new database.